# Finding derivative of $\sqrt{1 - k \cos^2 t}$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I'm solving this problem from a practice MIT calculus exam, and part (b) has me a bit perplexed.

> (a) Evaluate $\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{1 - k \cos^2 t}$.

> (b) Check your answer to part (a) by showing that if $k = 1$, your answer agrees witht he derivative calculated by a simpler method.

I didn't have much trouble solving part (a) by the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{1 - k \cos^2 t} = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 - k \cos^2 t\right)^{-3/2} \cdot - 2k \cos t \cdot - \sin t = \frac{k \cos t \sin t}{\sqrt{1 - k \cos^2 t}}.
\end{align*}
I couldn't figure out what (b) was even asking for before I peaked at the solution. If $k = 1$, I have
$$ 
\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 t} = \sqrt{\sin^2 t} = |\sin t|.
$$
The solution takes this to just be $\sin t$, And then differentiates it to get $\cos t$. If we plug $k = 1$ into the answer to $t$ and simplify the denominator, cancelling $\sin t$, we get $\cos t$.

What is the justification for dropping the absolute value? Or should I just break it into cases and deal with $t > 0$, $t < 0$, since $|\sin t|$ isn't differentiable at $t= 0$.

Comment: To be careful, the original result for the derivative simplifies to $\frac{\cos(t) \sin(t)}{|\sin(t)|}=\cos(t) \operatorname{sign}(\sin(t))$ when $k=1$. Simplifying first you effectively get $\operatorname{sign}(t) \sin(t)$ which becomes $\operatorname{sign}(\sin(t)) \cos(t)$ after differentiation. (All these statements are away from zeros of $\sin$.) So the results are equivalent on the whole domain if you're being careful.

Comment: "*The solution takes this to just be $\sin t$*" $\;-\;$ It helped if you quoted the solution in full. When $k=1$ the function is not differentiable at $t=n\pi$ so maybe the statement referred to some smaller interval.

Comment: @dxiv It's question 2 on the second page of this solution: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/exams/prexam1bsol.pdf. The solution doesn't say anything about picking a smaller interval.

Comment: @BradG. The given solution is indeed incomplete. Since it's just a "*check*", it would probably suffice to add "*assuming $t \in (0,\pi)$ we have $\sqrt{1-\cos^2 t}=\sin t$ then ... so the answer checks out on $(0,\pi)$*".

Comment: So the derivative of $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 t}$ is undefined for $t = 0, n\pi$, but I can pick either $(0, \pi)$ (where $\sin$ is positive) or $t \in (pi, 2\pi)$, where $\sin$ is negative, and I assume the same check is valid. Is that correct?

Comment: @BradG. Yes, you could break it down by intervals $(n\pi, (n+1)\pi)$ and prove that it matches the answer $(a)$ in all cases. Though it's hard to tell if they expect more than just a "sanity check", in which case proving it for $t \in (0,\pi)$ might suffice.